# Как можно реализовать данную карточку?

Tags: html, css

Испробовал уже несколько вариантов - через float, inline-block и flex, но верстка постоянно едет и возникает проблема с вертикальным выравниваем строк, одна выше другой.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте таблицу.... Я не думаю, что здесь особо правильно было бы с css заморачиваться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.box {
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 20px 20px;
}

.title {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.line {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.line_left {
  width: calc(65% - 10px);
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}

.line_right {
  width: 35%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="title">Заголовок</div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="line_left">Формат</div>
    <div class="line_right">Данные</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="line_left">Просмотр</div>
    <div class="line_right">Данные</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="line_left">Инструменты</div>
    <div class="line_right">Данные</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если вместо "Данные" будет более длинная строка, то все съезжает, что не есть хорошо